# Regular expression to obtain all substrings of length n

Tags: regex

Given an input string of only lower case letters and an integer `N`. I need a regular expression to extract all sub-strings of length `N` from the input string. As an example: `let N = 3` and `input string = "baababacb"` result should be: `"baa" "aab" "aba" "bab" "aba" "bac" "acb"`

I have tried: `([a-z]{3})` and in several attempts to make it non-greedy: `(?:[a-z]{3})` and `([a-z]{3}?)` but both don't produce the required output and I'm not sure i'm taking the right approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @zzzzBov are you suggesting that I delete the second paragraph?

Comment: not at all, I'm suggesting that you rewrite your question to be about your goal rather than your attempt. [Consider how simple a for loop is compared to a regular expression](http://jsfiddle.net/Lker521k/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex to get all 3-character strings:

```
(?=([a-z0-9]{3}))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI9hF8/1)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using C++ and that worked. (Although, the input consists of only lowercase letter, so I got rid of "0-9").

Comment: Yes that's correct, just for lowercase letters you can use: `(?=([a-z]{3}))`